# CVS - how file times are set in checkout operation

Tags: cvs

I have a several files stored in CVS.

I do a checkout/update and what to know, what atime, mtime and ctime will be assigned to each checkouted file. Does CVS sort files, based on what? Will CVS explicitly change some timestamps of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/CVS.html

> When you check out a file using ‘cvs checkout’ its timestamp is set to that of the revision that is being checked out.
>
> However, during cvs update, files will have the date of the update, not the original timestamp of this revision. This is meant to make sure that make notices sources files have been updated.

...

> CVS processes files in lexical order